# how to add to plot gaps when observations are missed?

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib

Here is what i got (time series) in pandas dataframe
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE34d.png)

(also dates were converted from timestamps)
My goal is to plot not only observations, but all the range of dates. I need to see horizontal line or gap when there is no new observations.

Comment: you need to provide 1- a reproducible dataset, as text/DataFrame constructor, 2- a mockup of the expected graph

Comment: With matplotlib you generally get breaks in a line plot where there are none/NaN values in the series.

Comment: @creanion the problem is that i dont have "none/NaN" values, they are just missed

Comment: @mozway https://ucarecdn.com/462399f3-4ca8-449a-bf55-677888679527/         here is data

Comment: how is that a problem? You can insert it where you need it, when you know where it should go :)

Comment: @creanion okay than tell me how to insert into dataframe NaN values for every one minute of empty observation?

Comment: Hey, that sounds like a great thing to add as a concrete question in the question here

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with data that is not observed equidistant in time is a typical challenge with real-world time series data. Given your problem, this code should work.

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample Frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : ['2022,7,3,0,1,21', '2022,7,3,0,2,47', '2022,7,3,0,2,47', '2022,7,3,0,5,5', 
                             '2022,7,3,0,5,5'], 
                   'balance' : [12.6, 12.54, 12.494426, 12.482481, 12.449206]})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S')
                   
# aggregate time duplicates by mean
df = df.groupby('time').mean()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# pick equidistant time grid
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'time' : pd.date_range(start=df.loc[0]['time'], end=df.loc[2]['time'], freq='S')})
df = pd.merge(left=df_new, right=df, on='time', how='left')

# fill nan
df['balance'].fillna(method='pad', inplace=True)
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)

# plot
_ = df.plot(title='Time Series of Balance')
```

[image]

There are several caveats to this solution.

**First**, your data has a high temporal resolution (seconds). However, there are hours-long gaps in between observations. You either coarsen the timestamp by rounding (e.g. to minutes or hours) or go along with the time series on a second-by-second resolution and accept the fact that most you balance values will be filled-in values rather than true observations.

**Second**, you have different `balance` values for the same timestamp which indicates faulty entries or a misspecified timestamp. I unified those entries via [grouping by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458361/python-pandas-groupby-date-and-accessing-each-group-by-timestamp) and averaged the `balance` over those non-unique timestamps.

**Third**, filled-up gaps and true observations both have the same visual representation in the plot (blue dots in the graph). As previously mentioned commenting out the `fillna()` line would only showcase true observations leaving everything in between white.

**Finally**, the missing values are merely filled in via padding. Look up different values of the argument `method` in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) in case you want to linearly interpolate etc.

**Summary**

The problems described above are typical for event-driven time series data. Since you deal with a (financial) `balance` that constitutes a state that is only changed by events (orders), I believe that the assumptions made above arew reasonable and can be adjusted easily for your or many other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

this helped

```
data = data.set_index('time').resample('1M').mean()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion.